# Changing script from PBS to SLURM

Tags: bash, slurm

I have just switched from PBS to SLURM. Originally my script read as:
Trying to change my script from PBS to SLURM. Before looked something like:

```
qsub -N $JK -e $LOGDIR/JK_MASTER.error -o $LOGDIR/JK_MASTER.log -v 
Z="$ZBIN",NBINS="$nbins",MIN="$Theta_min"  submit_MASTER_analysis.sh
```

Now need something like:

```
sbatch --job-name=$JK -e $LOGDIR/JK_MASTER.error -o $LOGDIR/JK_MASTER.log --export=Z="$ZBIN",NBINS="$nbins",MIN="$Theta_min"  
submit_MASTER_analysis.sh
```

But for some reason this is not quite executing the job, think its a problem with the variables.

Answer (score 0):

I have found out how to do this now so thought I better just update the post for anyone else interested.

In my launch script I now have

```
`sbatch --job-name=REALIZ_${R}_zbin${Z} \
        --output=$RAND_DIR/RANDOM_MASTER_${R}_zbin${Z}.log \
        --error=$RAND_DIR/RANDOM_MASTER_${R}_zbin${Z}.error \
        --ntasks=1 \
        --cpus-per-task=1 \
        --ntasks-per-core=1 \
        --threads-per-core=1 \
        submit_RANDOMS_analysis.sh $JK $ZBIN $nbins $R $Theta_min 'LOW'`
```

where `$JK $ZBIN $nbins $R $Theta_min 'LOW'` are the arguments I pas through to the script I am submitting to the queue `submit_RANDOMS_analysis.sh`. This is then called in the submitted script by for instance the first argument `JK=$1`.